# Where to package Class file so that both Client apps and EJBs on Server have access?

Tags: java, java-ee-6

I am new to the Java EE platform and I am building a simple JMS app. I created a class that is being sent in an ObjectMessage. My problem arose when both the client app creating the message and the MDB on the server needed access to the same class file(the class composed in the ObjectMessage). I currently have the class file in both the client library and EJB library and this is working. However I would like to have only one location for the class file where both the client and MDB can access it. I believe I need to package the entire app in a certain way, but I having a hard time figuring it out.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically most, if not all codesources (the locations from where classes are loaded) utilized by the application server's classloaders are located within the application server installation. In case of MDBs (or EJBs) for that matter, the codesources are contained within the EJB module (the EJB JAR file) or within the application archive (the EAR file). At runtime, the container manages where and how this code source is managed (including it's location), and there might not be a straightforward way to determine this location. In other words, it would be extremely difficult to use the deployed JARs in the container, in the classpath of your client application (assuming they are on the same machine).

The only possible way, I could think of using the same JARs in both the client app and by the application on the server, is to have a custom classloader on the server, that is configured to read specific classes from a common shared JAR. As a best practice, the classloader should always defer loading of classes to the parent classloaders, before attempting to resolve any class.

Your client may then, use the same shared JAR by setting the appropriate classpath (or by using the same custom classloader).

I should warn you that writing a custom classloader is not easy for some who haven't understood the classloading dynamics in a Java EE application server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So there is no way to lookup a class from the server so that the client can create and modify instances of it? I'm guessing I could also create an EJB that is injected into the client and allows the client to access the class kind of like a proxy.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. You could certainly lookup the class and create it, but you'll need to know where the class has been loaded from. This is not easy to do if it is a clustered deployment. But, if you do know where the classes are loaded from, you can re-use the same JAR in a different JVM. I'm not sure what you meant by injecting an EJB into the client - did you mean that your client has an embedded EJB container, or that your client would be using EJB references? The second case is not required, if this is a hobby project.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Placing the application in an EAR file and putting the selected JAR in the /lib directory solves the issue of having multiple copies of the same JAR.

Comment: Oh, it wasn't evident that the client was also deployed in the application server. I guess that info was missing. But anyway, putting the JAR in /lib under the EAR root is the standard way of sharing classes across modules in an enterprise archive.